# cutting column in file1 and replacing column in file2

Tags: multiple-columns, paste, cut

I am attempting to replace an entire column (column 2 in file 1) with column 3 of file 2. I know how to do this for one file with awk but I think using cut would be better as my file exceeds the amount of columns allowed by awk (see below)

The files is space separated and has a ton of columns... but I am only interested in replacing column 2 of file 1 with column 3 of file 2 and keeping everything else the same.

All lines match each other so there is no need to rearrange anything.

**Sample Files**

**File 1**

ID X A 2

ID A I 8

**File 2**

ID E 8 4

ID T 2 4

```
   awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$3;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' f2 f1
```

Receiving this error with using awk and multiple files.
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767

I think something like this should be what I should do...

```
cut -f3 file2 | paste -
```

but I dont know what to do to replace f2 in file1

Comment: I think using `cut` and then `paste` would be the best way to do this but I don't know how to do this for two files at once.

Comment: Do you really have more than 32,767 columns?  Or, might there be some other problem (like a nonstandard line termination)?

Comment: Yes I really do.

Comment: which is why I think cutting and pasting a column from one file is the easier option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cut -f1 file1 > temp.1
cut -f3 file2 > temp.2
cut -f3- file1 > temp.3post
```

## combining the files to get final output

```
paste temp.1 temp.3 temp.3post
```